# Why NLog ignores NLog.config file in project directory?

Tags: .net-core, nlog

I added NLog.Config 4.5.4 nuget package to my dotnet core application project.

This package created link to file

```
%USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages\nlog.config\4.5.4\contentFiles\any\any\NLog.config.
```

When I try to delete this link got error message

```
"Unable to erase files or folders: Can't modify file 'NLog.config', item doesn't belong the project and was imported from \obj\MyProject.csproj.nuget.g.props"
```

Then I created new file NLog.config in project folder, but when I build project this file is ignored and copied linked one.

Comment: Can you show your project file?